# compare table data row in Html table and to find wirte answer in Q & A quiz app

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to compare all rows with a specific row and highlight border:

```
<table *ngFor="let Question from Questions|  paginate: { itemsPerPage: 1, currentPage: p }">
   <tr><td>emp.question</td></tr>
   <tr><td>emp.option1</td></tr>
   <tr><td>emp.option2</td></tr>
   <tr><td>emp.option3</td></tr>
   <tr><td>emp.option4</td></tr>
   <tr><td>Emp.rightAnswer</td></tr>
</table>
```

if selected option equal to `rightAnswer` highlight tr border green otherwise
sectected option border red

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Could you provide some examples of the Javascript you've tried so far?

Comment: Can you please create a stackblitz for your question and share it here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My last answer was deleted before I can edit it, here is my complete answer

Please refer to the link below to get highlight for a row

https://ciphertrick.com/highlight-selected-row-in-ngfor-angular-2/

Edit :

I introduced two new classes : correctAnswer, wrongAnswer.

```
.table td.correctAnswer {
  background-color:green !important;
  color: white;
}
.table td.wrongAnswer {
  background-color:red !important;
  color: white;
}
```

Then added two properties for question's options : isSelected and isCorrectAnswser

```
Questions = [{
  question : "Question 1",
  options : [
    { option : "Q1-Option 1", isSelected : false , isCorrectAnswer : true},
    { option : "Q1-Option 2", isSelected : false , isCorrectAnswer : false},
    { option : "Q1-Option 3", isSelected : false , isCorrectAnswer : false},
    { option : "Q1-Option 4", isSelected : false , isCorrectAnswer : false},
  ]
}]
```

Then added an Angular directive class for both correctAnswer and wrongAnswer, and a click function for option to update isSelected value

```
setClickedRow = function(option){
  option.isSelected = !option.isSelected;
}
```

```
<table class="table table-hover table-sm">
   <tr *ngFor="let q of Questions">
      <td>{{q.question}}</td>
        <td *ngFor="let o of q.options" (click)="setClickedRow(o)" 
           [class.correctAnswer]= "o.isSelected && o.isCorrectAnswer"
           [class.wrongAnswer]  = "o.isSelected && !o.isCorrectAnswer"
        >
        {{o.option}}
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

You can find a demo here : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uyeq5y

Comment: can u please tell me questions(collection)/question1(docID)/options(subcollection)/and option is array in firebase is this right???